# findOne isn't working with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My find one isn't returning a result. I have tried a couple different things, but it doesn't seem to return the correct result. At least, I get no responses.

I have tried with this:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

m_Kbase_data.findOne( {_id : new Object(req.params.m_id)}, function(err, kbase_data){
```

Also, I have tried it without the Object.

I'm getting the result of

```
kbase_data.length === 0
```

However, when I run this:

```
m_Kbase_data.find({_id : req.params.m_id}, function(err, kbase_data){
```

I find the one and only correct document. I just think it is weird.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you:-

```
 var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
 var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; //For mongoose

 m_Kbase_data.findOne( {_id : new ObjectID(req.params.m_id)}, function(err, kbase_data){});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The object id is actually a string, so the code

```
{_id : req.params.m_id}
```

is right. Trying to do it with an object

```
{_id : new Object(req.params.m_id)}
```

would be the same as

```
{_id : {"0":req.params.m_id}}
```

and _id obviously contains no object

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectId instead of object in your query

```js
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

m_Kbase_data.findOne( {_id : new ObjectId(req.params.m_id)}, function(err, kbase_data){
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to cast the string to ObjectId as Mongoose already does that for you, just do

```
m_Kbase_data.findOne({_id: req.params.m_id}, function(err, kbase_data) { ... }
```

or use the [`findById()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) signature

```
m_Kbase_data.findById(req.params.m_id, function(err, kbase_data) { ... }
```